# Is the @Resource annotation applied when a Stateless EJB is deserialized?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

Is the `@Resource` annotation on a method applied when an `EJB` is deserialized? I have a EJB Timer thats persisted by the container and would like to know if the transient `TimerService` (it's not serializable) will be injected again when the EJB is deserialized.

Comment: Excellent question. No idea what the answer is…

Comment: do you mean "activated" (after passivation) ?

Comment: I think it won't be hard to try it.

Comment: @Bozho - Its a Stateless bean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this articles help:

- **Stateless Session Bean:** the stateless session EJB is injected at creation time, and keeps it's resources along its life time.
- **Stateful Session Bean:** It seems that the dependency injection only occurs at creation time. Anyway, after activation, the @PostActivate callback Handler is invoked, where you could recover your transient elements.

Edit for adding the Java EE Tutorial link on this subject, which confirms what is exposed:

- [The Life Cycles of Enterprise Beans](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbmt.html)

So, as a conclusion, the answer is no, the container won't inject again your transient resources after activation, but you can implement a PostActivate handler to do it by your own means.

Comment: Thanks for the `JEE tutorial` link. On Stateless Beans (http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbmt.html#bnbmw) `Because a stateless session bean is never passivated, its life cycle has only two stages: nonexistent and ready for the invocation of business methods.` The Timer EJB is most likely serialized so that it can exists across server restarts. However when its needed a and not available, new instance is always created, and dependency injection will work.